# error while try to import xsd schema to excel

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have the following schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="import">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="node">
            <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="action" type="xs:string" default="create"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" default="document"/>
                    <xs:element name="location" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="file" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string">
                      <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="language" type="xs:string" default="en"/>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    
                    <xs:element name="attribute">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:simpleContent>
                                <xs:extension>
                                    <xs:attribute name="name" use="required">
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                <xs:enumeration value="الجهة المرسل اليها"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="الجهة المرسلة للخطاب"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="الموضوع المختصر"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="تاريخ الحافظة"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="تاريخ المراسلة"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="رقم الخطاب الخاص بالجهة"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="رقم القرار"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="رقم المراسلة الخاص بالجهاز"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="عنوان الخطاب"/>
                                                <xs:enumeration value="كود المراسلة"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                </xs:extension>
                            </xs:simpleContent>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    
                    <xs:element name="category">
                      <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element ref="attribute" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>    
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

when I tried to import it inside excel it gives me the following error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your XSD:

1. Attribute declarations have to appear **after** the elements. Yes, it is one of the quirky "features" of XSD
2. Your elements in your `complexType` have to be in an `xs:sequence`.
3. You can only have either a `type=...` attribute on you elements or an `xs:complexType` child (or `xs:simpleType` of course, but here it doesn't matter).
4. `The` xs:extension`requires a`base`attribute. I set it to`xs:string`, guessing... change it if it doesn't fit.
5. I couldn't fix your last error which is a reference without a definition that is referred to:

   > Cannot resolve the name 'attribute' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.

   in the line

   ```
   <xs:element ref="attribute" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
   ```

---

So a (mostly) fiex version of your XSD looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="import">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="node">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="location" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="file" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="title">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="language" type="xs:string" default="en"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            
                            <xs:element name="attribute">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute name="name" use="required">
                                                <xs:simpleType>
                                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="الجهة المرسل اليها"/>
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="الجهة المرسلة للخطاب"/>
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="الموضوع المختصر"/>
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="تاريخ الحافظة"/>
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="تاريخ المراسلة"/>
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="رقم الخطاب الخاص بالجهة"/>
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="رقم القرار"/>
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="رقم المراسلة الخاص بالجهاز"/>
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="عنوان الخطاب"/>
                                                        <xs:enumeration value="كود المراسلة"/>
                                                    </xs:restriction>
                                                </xs:simpleType>
                                            </xs:attribute>
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            
                            <xs:element name="category">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element ref="attribute" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                                    
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="action" type="xs:string" default="create"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" default="document"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

As said above, the problem with the line

```
<xs:element ref="attribute" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

remains unsolved and I cannot infer a solution without the greater context, so I leave it to your expertise to fix that.